# Control android permissions at runtime

Tags: android, xml, runtime, android-permissions, user-permissions

I tried to delete\add  at runtime but I found that it is impossible

but I also found there is a way to remove it using *tools:node="remove"* =, the problem is
that I need to add this attribute to  tag at runtime

Do anyone know how to do it or is there a workaround solution to control the permissions
programmatically

Comment: "the problem is that I need to add this attribute to tag at runtime" -- that is not possible, sorry. "is there a workaround solution to control the permissions programmatically" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: I want to enable\disable the permissions from the code, as known the user has to go to the settings to set the applications permissions but for me I want him to control them from the app itself, is it possible ?

Comment: "as known the user has to go to the settings to set the applications permissions" -- those are runtime permissions. "I want him to control them from the app itself, is it possible ?" -- yes, that is how you are supposed to do it. However, it does not involve changing the manifest. You still need the `<uses-permission>` element, but you also use `ActivityResultContracts. [This sample Java project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor) demonstrate this.

Comment: is not that I want to ask for permission at runtime (I know it is possible and the way to do it) but I am asking if I can set permanent change to the manifest.xml each time the user change his permission

Comment: "I am asking if I can set permanent change to the manifest.xml each time the user change his permission" -- no, sorry.